# Does having multiple limit values at a point imply essential discontinuity?

Tags: complex-analysis

In Complex Analysis, do "jump discontinuities" exist?

If I find that a function of $z$ approaches two different values as z is approached from two different directions, can I immediately conclude that the point is an essential singularity? Or do other possibilities exist?

Comment: I think you're right: the function has an essential discontinuity. That's because the only possible singularities of an holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ are an eliminable singularity (so that the limit exists and is in $\mathbb{C}$), a pole (so that the limit exists and it is $\infty$) and an essential singularity.

Comment: Remember that this only works if the function is meromorphic.

Comment: True, I took for granted that the function in the question was meromorphic

Comment: @zach Thanks. Whats a quick way to check that my function is meromorphic?

Comment: @DanieleA : So why not post an answer that either contains or cites a _proof_ of what you assert?

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Done! Sorry for the delay :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the singularity is *isolated*, yes. However, take $f(z)=\log z$ (principal branch) and consider what happens when $z \to -1$ along paths in the upper and lower halfplanes respectively.

Comment: Now it's down to pedantic details of what is and isn't an essential singularity. Some definitions require one to be isolated, others don't.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a proof of what I've written in the comment to the question (when I wrote that, I was assuming in my mind than the singularity was isolated one).

Suppose that we have an holomorphic function $f\colon U\setminus \{p\} \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$, where $U\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is an open subset and $p\in U$ a point. We want to prove that

- $p$ is a removable singularity if and only if $\lim_{z\to p}f(z)=c\in \mathbb{C}$
- $p$ is a pole if and only if $\lim_{z\to p}f(z)= \infty$
- $p$ is an essential singularity if and only if $\lim_{z\to p}f(z)$ does not exists

We can suppose up to translation that $p=0$.

First, if $0$ is a removable singularity, then by definition there is an holomorphic function $g\colon U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ that extends $f$, so that $\lim_{z\to 0 }f(z)=g(0)\in \mathbb{C}$. Conversely, if the limit $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=c$ exists and belongs to $\mathbb{C}$, then we can define a function $g\colon U \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ by
$$ g(z)=\begin{cases} f(z) & \text{ if } z\ne 0 \\ c & \text{ if } z=0 \end{cases} $$
It is clear that this function is continuous and holomorphic on $U\setminus \{ p\}$ so that it is holomorphic on the whole of $U$, by Morera's theorem (this can be found for example in Cartan's "Elementary Theory of Analytical Functions of One or Several Complex Variables").

Now, if $f$ has a pole in $0$: this means that the Laurent series of $f(z)$ in $0$ is of the form

$$ f(z)=\sum_{n\geq N}a_n z^n $$

for a certain $N\geq 1$. This implies that the function $g(z)=z^Nf(z)$ is holomorphic, so that $\lim_{z\to 0}z^Nf(z)=a\in \mathbb{C}$, but since $N\geq 1$, this implies that $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=\infty$.

Instead, if $f$ has an essential singularity, then Casorati-Weierstrass' Theorem or Picard's Theorem tell us that the image through $f$ of an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $0$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$, so that the limit $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$ does not exists.

Conversely, if $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)=\infty$,then $0$ cannot be neither a removable singularity nor an essential singularity, for what we have proven before, so that it must be a pole. Now a similar reasoning proves that, if the limit does not exists, then the point must be an essential singularity,

Answer (score 1):

Your question did not specify the domain of definition of your function, so it's hard to give a precise answer. (You have also used $z$ to mean two different things in the same sentence.) However, your function definitely does not have a limit at $z$, which [does imply](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_singularity#Alternate_descriptions) that $z$ is an essential singularity of your function.

(I suspect you mean "essential singularity" rather than "essential discontinuity"; the latter means, by definition, that the limit does not exist, and so your function certainly has an essential discontinuity as well.)

Comment: Thanks. P.S. have edited the mistake.